# Valgrind: stdio.h's function "puts" allocates memory

Tags: c, valgrind

I just noticed that valgrind is showing that this code allocates memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world");
}
```

Result when compiled with `gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1)`:

```
==25080== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25080== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25080== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25080== Command: ./a.out
==25080== 
Hello world
==25080== 
==25080== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25080==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25080==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==25080== 
==25080== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25080== 
==25080== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25080== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why does it show that `puts` allocates memory?

Comment: I don't know if `puts` allocates memory or not, but it's possible that within `stdio.h` some memory is allocated initially for some reason, even though, I must be honest, I don't know exactly how valgrind proceeds with its inspections. I guess that the best answer to your question is to look directly at the source code of `stdio.h` and in particular of `puts`, which is available usually.

Comment: What happens if you remove `puts` and the include?

Comment: When I tested your program I got 0 allocs (using gcc (Debian 5.3.1-21))

Comment: Did you tried to add 'return 0;' and then run the program?

Comment: Use the source, if you make your way through it you'll see that a buffer is passed to the file.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then it shows that no memory is allocated

Comment: @denis that should not be necessary in the main function

Comment: @ErikW Try, instead of having `void` as parameters' specifications,  to have the usual `int main(int argc, char** argv) { ... `, and then, separately, i.e., by leaving the `void`, to return, e.g., `0` from the `main`...does that change something?

Comment: it's maybe not the function `puts` which is allocating memory, but it's writing "Hello world" which definetly allocates memory.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Why do you say that is "Hello world" which causes valgrind to report the allocation of memory?

Comment: The answer to "why does it show that puts allocates memory" is probably "because puts allocates memory". :-)

Comment: @nbro it may be not, I'm saying that it allocates memory too, and can be considered

Comment: @nbro: `int main(void)` is perfectly valid and should not change what the crt generates with any arguments.

Comment: @meJustAndrew: string literals are not allocated on the heap. They typically reside in the `.rodata` section.

Comment: @Olaf Indeed it was just a complete random guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GNU C Library ("glibc", the usual C runtime on Ubuntu) allocates memory for internal use the first time `stdout` is used for anything.  (It probably does the same for `stderr` and `stdin`.)  To see this happening, run your program under `gdb` and, after it reaches `main`, set breakpoints on `brk` and `mmap`, which are the system calls that ultimately get used to allocate memory.  Then continue.

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004ea: file test.c, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/zack/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:5
5     puts("Hello world");
(gdb) b brk
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7b183c0: file ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c, line 31.
(gdb) b mmap
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7ffff7b1bc00: file ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S, line 84.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00007ffff7a9f49c in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (
    fp=0x7ffff7dd6620 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at filedoalloc.c:128
#2  0x00007ffff7aac550 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (
    fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd6620 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at genops.c:418
#3  0x00007ffff7aab9d8 in _IO_new_file_overflow (
    f=0x7ffff7dd6620 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at fileops.c:820
#4  0x00007ffff7aaab8a in _IO_new_file_xsputn (
    f=0x7ffff7dd6620 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x400584, n=11) at fileops.c:1331
#5  0x00007ffff7aa18d8 in _IO_puts (str=0x400584 "Hello world") at ioputs.c:41
#6  0x00000000004004f4 in main () at test.c:5
```

You can see that the call stack goes through a bunch of internal stuff and ends up at `puts`.

Perhaps you are wondering *why* the library does this.  The reason is hinted at in Chuck Walbourn's answer: the memory will be used for buffering output, and it isn't allocated until `stdout` is used for the first time, because some programs never use `stdout` and they didn't want to waste memory.  (This design decision may have made more sense 20 years ago.)

Comment: The decision made more sense 40 years ago :) At this point the Standards committee is loathe to change these ancient functions for fear of breaking millions (billions?) of existing lines of code.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn You're not wrong about that, but, as far as I can tell this is a pure QoI issue - an implementation that statically allocated the default buffers for stdin/out/err would be equally conforming, as long as `setvbuf` still worked.

Comment: Why can't we see "malloc" in the backtrace? I would have assumed that they reuse their own guts, so they must have a good reason to not to?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In fact, glibc 2.22 changed this to use malloc instead of mmap: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16734  The original reason for using mmap seems to have been that "custom malloc implementations might not provide calloc" (see https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2006-11/msg00064.html, citing a "discussion from December 1996"); but a zeroed buffer seems no longer to be a requirement.  My stack trace was generated on Debian jessie, which is still on 2.19.

Answer (score 1):

Standard output [stdout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/) is allowed by the standard to be buffered by default. You can change this with [setvbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/).

Comment: While this is certainly true, I don't see how this clarifies the matter for the OP.

Comment: The question is "Why does it allocate memory?". The answer is "it buffers".